# Timed hiding of Bootstrap Tooltip does not work on rapid cursor motion

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

https://jsfiddle.net/d2gr1qu5/

In this fiddle I have code to hide a `manual` Bootstrap Tooltip on an `<img>` located inside a `<button>` after **2 sec**. In addition, I also manually hide it on `mouseleave` at all times.

It works most of the time, but if you rapidly move the mouse cursor in/out, sometimes you'll see instances where entering the area doesn't display the tooltip initially. A symptom of the problem is that something will flicker and disappear immediately.

```
$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'bottom'
});
$("[rel=tooltip]").on("mouseenter", function () {
    console.log('TOOLTIP: Entered mouseeneter');
    var that = $(this)
    that.tooltip('show');
    setTimeout(function () {
        that.tooltip('hide');
        console.log('TOOLTIP: Completed Hide after 2000');
    }, 2000);
});
$("[rel=tooltip]").on("mouseleave click", function () {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably [the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) that kicks in. You can disable the timeout when you leave the tooltip. I made a quick and dirty solution with a global `timeoutTooltip` variable:

```
var timeoutTooltip;

$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'bottom'
});

$("[rel=tooltip]").on("mouseenter", function () {
    console.log('TOOLTIP: Entered mouseeneter');
    var that = $(this)
    that.tooltip('show');
    timeoutTooltip = window.setTimeout(function () {
        that.tooltip('hide');
        console.log('TOOLTIP: Completed Hide after 2000');
    }, 2000);
});

$("[rel=tooltip]").on("mouseleave click", function () {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutTooltip);
});
```

The `timeoutTooltip` is used to clear the timeout when you leave the tooltip. I'm sure this can be coded nicer, but as it is it seems to work.

Comment: This is the jsFiddle with your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/zxuchbvs/ I still get rare moments of no tooltip when quickly moving in/out from all sides, but much less than before, maybe 10% rather than 50%. Thanks it is an improvement

Comment: @geneb. I've noticed that only the text in the button reacts to the mouse, not the whole button, like you would expect. You might want to attach the tooltip to the whole button.